# NullPointerException in RequestSpecification

Tags: java, api-testing, rest-api, rest-assured

Getting Null pointer exception whenever running, unable to resolve.

**Below is my code**

```
public static RequestSpecification setFormParam(String formParam, RequestSpecification reqSpec)
    {
        String[] splittedFormParam=formParam.split(",");
        System.out.println("NoOfFormParam:"+splittedFormParam.length);
        for(String s:splittedFormParam)
        {
            System.out.println("FormParam:-"+s);
            String[] keyValue=s.split(":");
            System.out.println("key-->"+keyValue[0]);
            System.out.println("Value-->"+keyValue[1]);
            System.out.println(reqSpec);// reqSpec Always getting null value
            reqSpec.formParam(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
            testCaseLogger.get().log(Status.INFO, "Added "+keyValue[0]+" as FormParam with value "+keyValue[1]);
        }


        return reqSpec;

    }
```

**Uses of  setFormParam method**

```
public static Response postCandidateResponse(Hashtable<String, String> data) {

        requestSpec=    TestUtils.setFormParam(data.get("formParam"), requestSpec);
        extentLogger().log(Status.INFO, " Method type is: "+data.get("methodType"));
        extentLogger().info("EndPoint is: "+data.get("endPoint"));
        return requestSpec.request(data.get("methodType"),data.get("endPoint"))
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide exception stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried to see what `NullPointerException` stands for? Have you looked at your stacktrace? See this answer to see how to read stacktraces and understand exceptions: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/51649/1933

Answer (score 2):

Now take a look at `setFormParam()` method:

```
System.out.println(reqSpec);// reqSpec Always getting null value
reqSpec.formParam(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
```

and then at `postCandidateResponse()` that calls `setFormParam()`:

```
public static Response postCandidateResponse(Hashtable<String, String> data) {

   requestSpec=    TestUtils.setFormParam(data.get("formParam"), requestSpec);
```

In the code you listed you never initialize original `requestSpec`.

Then how would you expect it to have non-null value?